# Serving a file from an action in Asp.Net MVC. Is it better to use byte[] or Stream?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, file, stream

When we want to serve a file (non HTML) from an action we can use the File Action Result. The contructor can accept either a byte[] or a Stream. Which one is better? Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a stream and I would try hard to stream data down to the client **without** ever load all data into a `byte[]` on the web server.

This is the only way you are sure you do not load files completely in the server memory, imagine 10 people downloading files of 100 Mb each, better to avoid the ASP.NET process to grow to 1GB RAM only because of that, with streaming you can do this :)

Comment: While a reasonable answer, the assumption here is that the content is large. It is entirely possible that the content is *known* to be reasonably small, in which case `byte[]` is perfectly acceptable (and may be more convenient).

Comment: @Marc, can you ever predict how many users will download how many files at the same time?

Comment: I was also thinking of this. I'm generating my files on the fly (using iText or EPPlus) so I don't know how big will they end up to be.

Comment: @Davide the relevance is unclear... if the content is small it may commonly be *smaller* than the default buffers allocated by most stream operations. The alloc/collection of a small, short-lived array is negligible. If it truly is a "file", then there are additionally overloads that accept the path, so I assume we are generating on the fly etc; if the generated content is *identical*, cache it!

Answer (score 2):

Neither is better or worse, use whichever one most suits your situation.

For eaxmple, if the file is on disk, it's probable that you will load it into a stream

```
var stream = File.OpeanRead("C:\myfile.ext")
```

There is no point turning this into a byte array.

However, if you have a file in memory, it might already be in a byte array. In this case there is no point turning it to a stream.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is on disk, you can use FilePathResult : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filepathresult.aspx

This class uses HttpResponse.TransmitFile, which reads the file without buffering it to memory : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.transmitfile.aspx